# Getting current time in iOS

Tags: ios, nsdate, nstimezone

I am trying to get current time, for this I know how to get it, below is my code

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar]; 
NSDateComponents *weekdayComponents3 = [calendar components:(NSDayCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit |NSSecondCalendarUnit)fromDate:[NSDate date]];

NSInteger hour = [weekdayComponents3 hour];
NSInteger min = [weekdayComponents3 minute];
NSInteger sec = [weekdayComponents3 second];
```

Now I just want to add 1 hour to current time and get the immediate next hour for example if current time 6.10 pm I should get 7.00pm , if current time 6.45pm , then also I should get 7.00pm

For this I wrote this code

```
 NSDateComponents *timeZoneComps1=[[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [timeZoneComps1 setDay:day];
    [timeZoneComps1 setMonth:month];
    [timeZoneComps1 setYear:year];
    [timeZoneComps1 setHour:hour+1];
    [timeZoneComps1 setMinute:00];
    [timeZoneComps1 setSecond:01];

    NSDate *reqiredDate  = [calendar dateFromComponents:timeZoneComps1];
```

I got it right using this code.

Now here starts my confusion,

if I set time zone to UTC

```
 [calendar setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];
```

and try with the above code, I get immediate next hour as  for example if current time 6.10 pm I get 7.30pm , if current time 6.45pm , then I get 7.30pm

The same case if I try to US time zone **(by changing time zone through settings in device and not through code)**, here I get correct immediate next hour, again for example if current time 6.10 pm I  get 7.00pm , if current time 6.45pm , then  I get 7.00pm

So I am not understanding why these different behaviours and secondly how to make it consistent.

I think it is due to the offset to UTC, but not sure.

Comment: If it's due to the "UTC offset" why don't you first set the time zone and *then* set the date component for minutes and seconds to 0?

Comment: @Mischa, I am doing that only

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce your issue. What is your timezone?

Comment: Why do you think the results are wrong?  NSLog always displays times as local time, so if your local time has a non-full hour UTC offset, you'll get the results you're reporting.

Comment: @David, I am setting reminders and I want to set it to immediate next hour, but  it is adding half hour extra to it.

Comment: IST is offset by 30 minutes, so if you apply this algorithm to a UTC time, then the local time is going to be offset by 30 minutes as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you push 00:10 UTC through your algorithm you get 01:00 UTC.  Since IST is UTC+6:30, in local times you see 06:40 becomes 07:30.

Likewise, if you take 18:10 local time (IST) convert that to UTC you get 11:40.  Run that through and you get 12:00 UTC.  Convert back to local time and you get 18:30.

You're going to have to go back to the requirements and figure out if the alarm time should be determined relative to UTC (unlikely) or local time (seems more reasonable) and then remove setting the timezone if you want them to be local time.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4

```
func getCurrentTime(){

    let strDateTime: String = "Current Time: " + String(describing: Date())

    print(strDateTime)
}
```